# How to pull account history data from MT4/MT5 terminal and send to Next Js app

Tags: next.js, mql4, metatrader4, mql5

I’m trying to figure out a way to pull account and trade history data from MQL4 or 5 terminals and send it to my next js app to store in the backend but having trouble getting account balance history data.

What are some methods of doing this?

Is there a way to get the user to put in their username and investor password and get the data via an api or something?

I have built an ea that gets trade data and can send it via a post request

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.